# Bayesian optimization resulting in overfitting despite split test train

Tags: cross-validation, boosting, overfitting, hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization

I am using XGBRegressor on a time series to predict the next periods value. I use sklearns TimeSeriesSplit to split the data into test and train.

[image: Text]

I use skopts BayesSearchCV to search through a parameter space to give me the best parameters. Unfortunately, I notice that when I run the bayesian search, the top set of parameters it returns are obviously overfitted. For example:

```
model = XGBRegressor(alpha=0, colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1,
eta=0.06566805511633206, gamma=0, reg_lambda=0, max_depth=5, min_child_weight=2, subsample=1,
num_boost_round=3000)
```

Based on the XGB documentation https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/param_tuning.html

The lower the: alpha, lambda, and gamma values are, the more prone the model is to overfitting. Similarly the higher the colsample, subsample, and max_depth values are, the more prone the model is to overfitting.

What I fail to understand is how the overfitted parameters are scoring better than non-overfitted parameters in the test set, and how do I avoid this overfitting? I tried reducing the size of the training set to match the size of the testing set, but this doesn't work either, resulting in this:

[image: Hyperparameter heatmap]

Comment: Bays. Optim. is a great technique but given that you get "unreasonable" results it probably more sensible to try to validate them externally. For example, if you think that you model if "over-fitted" with `gamma=0, reg_lambda=0, max_depth=5` try one with `gamma=0.1, reg_lambda=0.1, max_depth=4` (or some other "less over-fitted" parameters) and see if your validation procedure actually returns a better cost. Also note that if you "most overfitted" parameters are the "best" maybe you actually *underfit* so you need to explore even more flexible models. (Assuming your CV procedure is valid.)

Comment: I believe I found the problem, seemed to be that my parameter space was too big, messing up the bayesian search optimizer.

Comment: Cool. Can you please write it as an answer (with some details)?